# Are vector components "normalized" in generic vector differential operater expressions, e.g., divergence?

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, vectors, vector-fields

A typical way of writing the expression for the divergence of a vector field in general orthogonal coordinates is:

$$\nabla\cdot\vec{A}=\frac{\partial_{u}\left[VWA^{u}\right]+\partial_{v}\left[WUA^{v}\right]+\partial_{w}\left[UVA^{w}\right]}{UVW}.$$

I read the expression as ambiguous.  I believe the components $\left\{A^i\right\}$ are assumed to be rectangular, Cartesian, which I am calling "normalized".
That is, there are two common ways of writing a vector in such coordinates.  One is to contract with the coordinate basis

$$\vec{A}=\mathbf{e}_{u}A^{u}+\mathbf{e}_{v}A^{v}+\mathbf{e}_{w}A^{w},$$

where

$$\mathbf{e}_{u}=\partial_{u}\vec{r},$$
$$\mathbf{e}_{v}=\partial_{v}\vec{r},$$
$$\mathbf{e}_{w}=\partial_{w}\vec{r}.$$

The other way is

$$\vec{A}
=\mathbf{e}_{\hat{u}}A^{\hat{u}}
+\mathbf{e}_{\hat{v}}A^{\hat{v}}
+\mathbf{e}_{\hat{w}}A^{\hat{w}},$$

where

$$\mathbf{e}_{\hat{u}}U=\mathbf{e}_{u},$$
$$\mathbf{e}_{\hat{v}}V=\mathbf{e}_{v},$$
$$\mathbf{e}_{\hat{w}}W=\mathbf{e}_{w}.$$

The latter form is what I am calling normalized.  So I am asking if, using this notation, the correct form of the divergence is

$$\nabla\cdot\vec{A}=\frac{
\partial_{u}\left[VWA^{\hat{u}}\right]
+\partial_{v}\left[WUA^{\hat{v}}\right]
+\partial_{w}\left[UVA^{\hat{w}}\right]}{UVW}?$$

It seems as if it has to be in terms of "normalized" components, or we would need additional $U,V,W$ factors under the partial derivatives.

Comment: If you already know that the first equation is right, then the last equation must be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself well.  I am adding my notation to clarify the situation.  The first equation is "generic", and I'm not sure which vector representation is assumed in the generic form.

Comment: I think your presentation is unclear. It is the basis vectors not the components which are normalized when you use ${\bf e}_{\hat{u}}$. Also you propose that the phrase "rectangular, Cartesian" can refer either to non-unit basis vectors, or to unit basis vectors, but I always understood "Cartesian" to mean orthonormal basis vectors by definition.

Comment: So in what sense is the first equation "generic"? Like, what does that mean to you?

Comment: @AndrewSteane If I normalize the basis vectors, I have to adjust the components accordingly.  So, normalized components are those which have been adjusted to compensate for the normalized basis.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin It's what I find when I look it up.

Comment: ... well of course, but in that case one says "normalized basis vectors" not "normalized components". Or you could say "components when the basis is orthonormal". My aim is that the reader should glean what you wish to ask, without the need for mind-reading.